# Ошибка при внесении данных в таблицу SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite

В базе данных SQLite есть следующая таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE "LimitParams" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "signalId"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "startDate" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "endDate"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "minValue"  REAL NOT NULL,
    "maxValue"  REAL NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

В программе имеется класс LimitParamsModel

```
public class LimitParamsModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int SignalId { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan StartDate { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan EndDate { get; set; }
        public float MinValue { get; set; }
        public float MaxValue { get; set; }
    }
```

Я пытаюсь выполнить следующий запрос на вставку данных:

```
"Insert into LimitParams (signalId, startDate, endDate, minValue, maxValue) VALUES(" + (limitParams.SignalId.ToString()) + ", " + (limitParams.StartDate.Ticks.ToString()) + ", " + (limitParams.EndDate.Ticks.ToString()) + ", " + (limitParams.MinValue.ToString()) + ", " + (limitParams.MaxValue.ToString()) + ")";
```

При этом я получаю исключение:

```
{"SQLite Error 1: '7 values for 5 columns'."}
```

Почему такое может происходить?

Comment: *Я пытаюсь выполнить следующий запрос на вставку данных* А как бы обойтись без кода сборки, а? Покажите текст ГОТОВОГО запроса, после всех подстановок/конкатенаций..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никогда не используйте конкатенацию строк для формирования запроса. Это во-первых небезопасно, во-вторых можно натворить синтаксических ошибок. Откуда гарантии, что ни в одной из ваших строк нет запятых? В кавычки строки надо брать в самом запросе.

А более верным решением будет использовать запрос с параметрами, и пусть библиотека Microsoft.Data.Sqlite сама решает, как правильнее передать данные в БД, а не вы. Нужно лишь указать, какой именно [тип данных](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/types) ожидает база с помощью перечисления [`DbType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dbtype).

```
using var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
var command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.Text = "INSERT INTO LimitParams (signalId, startDate, endDate, minValue, maxValue) VALUES ($signalId, $startDate, $endDate, $minValue, $maxValue)";

command.Parameters.Add("$signalId", DbType.Int32).Value = limitParams.SignalId;
command.Parameters.Add("$startDate", DbType.Int64).Value = limitParams.StartDate.Ticks;
command.Parameters.Add("$endDate", DbType.Int64).Value = limitParams.EndDate.Ticks;
command.Parameters.Add("$minValue", DbType.Single).Value = limitParams.MinValue;
command.Parameters.Add("$maxValue", DbType.Single).Value = limitParams.MaxValue;

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Есть ещё перечисление [`SqliteType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqlitetype), попробуйте использовать его вместо `DbType`, но я не проверял.

Comment: Нет ли готового популярного C# ответа на эту тему, чтобы проставить дубликат? На питоне то есть типовой ответ про параметры запросов, я туда уже тучу вопросов задупликатил.

Comment: @CrazyElf про SQLite я не нашёл.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, каждый из limitParams.MinValue.ToString() и limitParams.MaxValue.ToString() выдаёт число с запятой в качестве десятичного разделителя, что воспринимается как два параметра вместо одного числа.

Чтобы получить строковое представление числа с десятичной точкой, используйте:

```
using System.Globalization;
...
    NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo() { NumberDecimalSeparator = "." };
    limitParams.MinValue.ToString(nfi);
    limitParams.MaxValue.ToString(nfi);
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть так же проблема в типах данных, вы используете TimeSpan для StartDate и EndDate, тогда как в базе данных SQLite у вас тип данных INTEGER для этих столбцов.
Попробуйте так

```
string query = $"INSERT INTO LimitParams (signalId, startDate, endDate, minValue, maxValue) VALUES ({limitParams.SignalId}, {limitParams.StartDate.Ticks}, {limitParams.EndDate.Ticks}, {limitParams.MinValue}, {limitParams.MaxValue});";
```

Comment: Это не то, там используется `limitParams.StartDate.Ticks`, что представляет из себя int. И `ToString()` будет всё равно вызываться автоматически. Но поскольку команда - это строка, то нужно преобразовывать все значения к строчному виду. Даже если заключить число в кавычки, оно будет воспринято как число, если нужно (может, не во всех СУБД).